# Can i add, modify and remove folders using minor upgrade in installshield

Tags: upgrade, installshield

I need to add, modify, remove and change folder structure and send it as a upgrade file. Can i achieve this with minor upgrade feature in the Install-shield software. Explain the difference between small, minor and major upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Installation projects usually do not operate with bare "files" and "folders", instead they operate with "features" and "components". This is exactly you should be looking for in your existing project. As the simple answer you can remove or add folders with minor upgrade, but this is not a good idea. You should be operating with features and components to re-structure your project and add/remove folders and files.

This is the first line of Google search for your question "Explain the difference between small, minor and major upgrades." : [Major Upgrade vs. Minor Upgrade vs. Small Update](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm). Please consider do more reading before posting the question.